# Beneficent touch before or after roll?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

In the trait [Beneficent Touch](http://archivesofnethys.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Beneficent%20Touch) it says the following:

> Once per day, when you cast a spell or use a class ability that heals hit point damage, reroll any 1s that appear on the dice and take the new roll (even if it is another 1).

Can I use this ability after the dice have been rolled, or do I have to declare it before-hand?

This is for PFS, so I'd prefer an official ruling (not necessarily for this particular trait though of course - other similar situations fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have to decide to use an ability before doing the roll it is clearly indicated. Here nothing is specified, which means you can decide to apply it whenever you want (so usually after rolling your dice, when you see all these nasty 1s).

To convince you, look at something like the [Oathbound](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/faith-traits/oathbound) trait:

> Once per day, you may reroll a saving throw against a charm or compulsion effect. You must take the second result even if it is worse.

If you have to choose to activate it before rolling the first die it just means you have to roll a die for nothing and then perform your real die roll.

Oathbound is only one example, there are other capacities that works the same way.

Comment: Anything to back up that that is the intention, or is it just an observation? I was kind of thinking along these lines too, and if there's nothing else out there I'll accept, but I'll leave it a couple days.

Comment: here an example, hope it will convince you !

Comment: Seems legit. D20s are often quite different to other dice in terms of rules, but it doesn't seem like there's much else on the topic